# Why does the nested quasiquote not unwrap splice-unquote?

Tags: macros, scheme

Why does the first macro `unquote-splicing` not produce `(quasiquote (unquote (quasiquote 1 2)))`, but the second example replaces the value?

```
(define x (list 1 2))
```

```
(t '(quasiquote (unquote (quasiquote (unquote-splicing x))))
   (quasiquote (quasiquote (unquote (quasiquote (unquote-splicing x))))))

(t '(quasiquote (unquote (quasiquote (unquote (1 2)))))
   (quasiquote (quasiquote (unquote (quasiquote (unquote (unquote x)))))))
```

Comment: You need one more `unquote` to escape three `quasiquote`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first example

```
(quasiquote (quasiquote (unquote (quasiquote (unquote-splicing x)))))
```

This has 3 quasiquotes and 2 unquotes, so 'x' will not be evaluated.

in the second example

```
(quasiquote (quasiquote (unquote (quasiquote (unquote (unquote x))))))
```

there are 3 quasiquotes and 3 unquotes so 'x' will be replaced by it's value.